# Is it a good method to reduce electricity bill

Tags: electrical-engineering

It has become too hot to switch off the air-conditioners.So I read somewhere the aircons works better in higher humidity than dry air because it said AC compresses humidity which takes out the heat from air .

I actually live in a very dry environment . Is it a good idea to create a lot of steam in my room to increase it's efficiency.

Does switching AC on and off again and again increase my electricity bill .As I noticed in April I was frequently switching on and off the AC. It was roughly like i will switch it on for half an hour and switch it off for half an hour again. But in May i switched on the AC for like 2 hour and switched it off for an hour . But the bills of May and april were almost same. Is just a coincidence ?

Comment: Short answer, “no”.

Answer (score 1):

Air conditioners definitely do NOT work better in a high humidity environment.  Maybe the idea is that you can tell it's worked better?

It takes energy to remove humidity from air.  This is energy that does not go into cooling down the air.  So please do not add steam to your room - the heat to make it goes into the air, and the air conditioner will have to expend its capacity to remove it.

Your energy bill will be proportional to how often the unit is running.  It is marginally better to leave it off for longer and then let the temperature improve over a longer time, but I doubt it's a significant difference.  If you want to save money, set the thermostat to a higher temperate and use fans to keep cool.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't add steam.

However, allowing water to evaporate might improve the overall comfort of the air conditioning.

You do not want to add any heat to the room air if it is hot. So don't heat water to create vapor. But letting water evaporate on it's own doesn't add heat to the air, and if the room's dew point is slightly higher than the cold coil temperature, the coil will be wet with condensation and that can increase efficiency and total heat removal. The mechanism here is that the room air doesn't change temperature as much passing through the cold coil for a given amount of heat removal, making better use of the coil surface area.

A/Cs are designed for economy of operation and for economy of manufacturing. The standardized testing/rating conditions drive these designs to all be very similar. If you could custom design an A/C system just for your conditions, it wouldn't help to add humidity at all, but since your A/C was designed for standard test conditions, it helps a little bit to push the room conditions in that direction, which results in a small amount of condensation being removed.

All else being equal, if the room's wet bulb temp is below 67 F, letting some water evaporate will probably help. If the evaporator coil is bone dry, letting some water evaporate will probably help. If the unit is designed to route the condensate to condenser coil, then you get even more benefits. This is a common feature of window shakers that sling condensate on the condenser coil. Minisplits and some split systems also employ this trick.

Comment: helping efficiency is not the same as reducing the electric bill.  Adding any latent heat to the room will reduce cooling and cause the unit to run more.

Comment: @TigerGuy But you aren't adding any latent heat with evaporation. Imagine a closed loop system where the condensate is re-evaporated in the room. This can still improve efficiency and lower the bill because the setup is closer to the typical design point.

Comment: that does make sense, and the initial evaporation of the dish or whatever would lower the sensible heat load.  But I doubt this would be a measurable change.  If the humidity is low, the right answer is probably an evaporative cooler.

Comment: @TigerGuy https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/06cd/5340e72c958b9ffe11f5ca03722af437bb14.pdf